# THREE.js make texture repeat when model scales instead of stretching

Tags: three.js, glsl

If I have a square object in my scene that is textured, and I resize it, is there any way to have the texture repeat so that it doesn't stretch? Only way I can think of is making a very complicated pixel shader and pass the new scale to it, but that would take way too much time. There must be a simpler way, if not any solution would do as this is time sensitive.

Comment: [`THREE.Texture`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/Texture) has a `.repeat` property.

Comment: I'm using that:

 r_.traverse( ( o ) => {
   if(o.isMesh){
    o.material.uniforms.map.value.wrapS = o.material.uniforms.map.value.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
 o.material.uniforms.dimension.value = 10*m;
   }});


m is the variable that scales it, r_ is the gltf model

Comment: Modify the UVs. If they are for the full area you won't get repeat but stretch.

Comment: modify how? I just made a plane in blender, subdivided it and used auto unwrap, if I must modify them in the shader how should I go about it if I may ask? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, thanks for @antont's suggestion

```
<script id='rooffragment' type='x-shader/x-fragment'>
    uniform sampler2D map;
    varying vec2 vUv;
    uniform float dimension;
    void main() {
        vec2 uv_coord = vUv;
        uv_coord.x *= dimension;
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(map, uv_coord);
    }
</script>
```